# Using a usercontrol in c#

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

I have created a custom UserControl that includes several text boxes and radio buttons.  I want to place this UserControl onto several panels that I'm using for a wizard.

How can I actually use this UserControl? i.e I want to drag and drop it onto each of my panels? How do I do this?

Or is there a container that I can drop onto the panel and then set it to my user control?

Comment: do you make use of wpf or are you trying to create a winforms applicaton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure the UserControl class is part of your project or is inside a project that's included with your Solution.  After you build your program, your user control will appear at the top of the toolbox.  Drag it onto a form or panel, as desired.

If you don't see the control appear then you may have a setting wrong.  Tools + Options, Windows Forms Designer, General.  Ensure that "Automatically Populate Toolbox" is set to True.

Answer (score 1):

Press "F6" (edit: or any other key which rebuilds the project - "F6" is standard in Vs2010) and it will appear in the Toolbox in the designer, then you can drag and drop it. Note that always when you change something at a UserControl you first have to rebuld the project for the changes to take effect.

To do it programmatically:

```
UserControl myUI = new UserControl();
/// Blah blah
this.Controls.Add(myUI);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually when make a userControl, save it and Run your application that control should appear on top of Toolbar...

[image: Like in this image]